# How can I retain zero-length values during the $unwind phase of the aggregate pipeline in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm writing a Mongo query using the aggregate pipeline. During the aggregation, I need to `$unwind` one of the fields. However, I don't want the `$unwind` to exclude entries that have zero-length arrays for that field, because I still need them further down the pipeline.

My field is called `items` and it's an array of objects, which each contain two values: `quantity` and `price`. Here's a snippet of my Mongo query so far:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: ... },
    {$project: ... },
    // put another $project here to retain zero-length values? how to format it?
    {$project: {
            _id: "$$ROOT",
            items: {
                $ifNull: [
                    {
                        $literal: {
                            quantity: 0,
                            price: 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$items"},
    {$group: ... },
    {$project: ... },
    ...
]);
```

As you can see, this already handles the case where a document doesn't have the `items` field present at all, in which case it adds it in and gives it an empty value to unwind on.

What isn't handled, however, are documents that *do already* have that `items` field present, but it's blank. I was thinking I could use some combination of `$cond` and `$size` to check explicitly for a size of zero within another `$project`, and then substitute the same literal in that case, but `$if` expects a boolean so I'm not quite sure how to format that.

Comment: What do you mean by `items is blank` ? `items:[]`? or items:"" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your `project` stage in the pipeline as below:

The `projection` stage does the following two things:

- If the items array is `null` or `does not exist`, calculates the
  items field value as `[]`(an empty array.)
- Next checks if the `size` of the just calculated `items` field is `0`, if
  it is `0`, then changes its value to an array with default object.

Stage code:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
...
{$project:{"_id":"$$ROOT",
           "items":{$cond:[
                          {$eq:[{$size:{$ifNull:["$items",[]]}},0]},
                          [{"quantity":0,"price":0}],
                          "$items"
                          ]}}},
{$unwind:"$items"},
...
])
```